# Chamar um método de uma classe Javascript (OOP)

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Bom pessoal gostaria de saber se é possivel acessar um metodo de uma classe(javascript) sem sem saber se a variavel por instancia-la.

```
function SDK(dynamicUrl) {
    var data = 'DATA';
    var atual = null;
    var counter = 0;
    this.onComplete = function (){ }
    this.onError = function () { }
    this.start = function ( ) {
        alert('HUE BR')
    }
}
//Tendando acessar o metodo
SDK.start();
```

*Sei que poderia acessa-la criando uma variavel e instanciar a classe em questão, mas por uma limitação do projeto em questão isso não é possível T.T

```
var sdk = new SDK('HUE BR');
sdk.start();
```

URL do script:
http://jsfiddle.net/8twxajLh/

Comment: Porque não usa diretamente `SDK.start = function() {...}`. Nesse caso está criando uma função dentro de uma função (que é um objeto).

Comment: Então desse jeito não posso porque não tenha acessar os dados da instancia em questão mas mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Comment: Diretamente de `SDK` não dá. Por que você não pode usar `new`?

Comment: Então cara é uma limitação do projeto( sou responsavel por parte do script ), porque no meu caso não sou o responsavel por criar o new SDK(), ou seja não tenho acesso a variavel só tenho acesso a classe T.T;
Mas valew msm assim se não tiver jeito msm vou tentar outra coisa

Comment: Se você tem uma referência à classe, mesmo que não seja a própria classe, você ainda assim pode criar uma instância dela - veja o exemplo em http://jsfiddle.net/d3a5ozvo/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lendo a [resposta do Rui Pimentel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29544/74), me ocorreu que você pode criar uma instância dentro da própria função, se ela for chamada sem `new`. A consequência prática disso é que tanto faz chamar com ou sem o `new`:

```
function SDK(dynamicUrl) {
    if(!(this instanceof SDK)) {
       return new SDK(dynamicUrl);
    }
    var data = 'DATA BITCH';
    var atual = null;
    var counter = 0;
    this.onComplete = function (){ }
    this.onError = function () { }
    this.start = function ( ) {
        alert('HUE BR')
    }
}
SDK().start();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/164geejk/

Não tenho certeza se isso resolve o problema dadas as suas limitações, mas fica a dica.

Comment: Puts, cara deu certo !!! muito obrigado, cabaçada minha desconhecia o instanceof( com certeza devo utiliza-lo muitas vezes ) 
Valew !!!

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos escolhe a resposta do bfavaretto, então, para que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema se beneficiem da solução!

Answer (score 4):

Não, você não pode acessar uma variável de instância sem ter uma instância para tal. A função `start` só é criada quando da criação de uma instância da classe `SDK`. Você pode usar alguns artifícios para não chamar o `new SDK()` que por trás dos panos terminariam chamando o "construtor", mas isso só iria adicionar complicação desnecessária no seu código.

Comment: Concordo totalmente. Exemplo de artifício: http://jsfiddle.net/qabb81py/

Comment: Muito obrigado senhores ficou bem claro agora, vou achar outra solução VALEW!

Answer (score 3):

Se você puder adicionar a linha

```
return this;
```

como última da declaração da função/classe `SDK`, então é possível chamar a função desejada instanciando (`var a = new SDK(); a.start();`) **ou não** o protótipo (`SDK().start();`).

Edit: conforme apontado pelo @bfavaretto, este método tem o efeito colateral de declarar, no objeto global (`window`), os métodos (e possivelmente os atributos) da classe que tenham sido declarados com `this.metodo = function( ... ){ ... };`, assim que a função for executada (`SDK().start()`), pois, neste caso, o `this` da função será o próprio `window`.

Comment: Obrigado Rui, dentro da limitação( não sou responsavel por todo o codigo ), realmente ñ é possivel chamar a função sem saber a variavel que instancia a classe. Vou procurar outra solução.
Muito Obrigado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16536/discussion-between-bfavaretto-and-rui-pimentel).

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta após a discussão. A conclusão é que HÁ uma solução ideal para o problema do OP, e ela foi apontada na resposta do @bfavaretto.

Comment: Deu certo, Valew !